# How to remove duplicate ids from within a div, but keeping the original

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, duplicates, identifier

**Disclaimer:** I am fully aware that the `id` attribute is for `unique` IDs. In my case, when the ajax request takes longer than usual it can glitch, causing two same chat messages. I am also aware that there are similar questions out there like this, but I have been unable to find one that solves my issue.

---

This is what I want to do:

1. Are there any duplicate IDs inside the div `chat_log`?
2. What are they?
3. Delete **all** the duplicates

   - *Making sure* that the original one is still there.

---

I've tried using the following code:

```
         $('[id]').each(function () {
            var ids = $('[id=' + this.id + ']');
            if (ids.length > 1 && ids[0] == this) {
                $(ids[1]).remove();
            }
        });
```

But I'm not sure how I can adapt that method to my situation, nor am I sure if it would be possible.

Comment: You say you tried that code... did it work? Are you asking for help changing that code for your situation or are you saying that is what you tried and it didn't work so you need a different solution?

Comment: That code will work (potentially add the `#chat_log` selector). However, appending duplicate-id content should never be risked depending on ajax loading times. Show us your app logic, there must be a flaw in it.

Comment: @MrOBrian I should have been more clear on that. But didn't you read "I've tried using the following code:"? Anyway, I am open to a different solution, but at the same time, if it's easier for you, fixing the current code.

Comment: @JordanRichards: Yes, we read that line. But you didn't gave us any information why it would not have worked for you; what feature needs an adaption?

Comment: Yes, I did read "I've tried using the following code:" which is why I said "You say you tried that code". What you did _not_ say, however, is whether that code worked at all, errored, worked in different situation but not this one, etc.

Comment: @MrOBrian Oh, I understand now. Sorry, mistake on my part there. I tried it and it did not work in my solution. I think a different solution/approach would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can you ensure that something is unique? Let's say you have a bunch of vegetables (cucumbers, turnips, pizzas etc.) You want to ensure colour uniqueness, making sure that any colour only appears once. How'd you do it?

What I'd do is make a list. I'd go through every vegetable, and inspect its colour. If the colour is already on the list, we'll remove that vegetable from the bunch. Otherwise, we leave it as-is and add its colour to our list.

Once that logic is understood, all we need is to convert it to code! What a fantastically trivial thing to do (on paper, of course.)

```
//assumes $elem is the element you're deleting duplicates in

//create the ids list we'll check against
var ids = {};

//go over each element
var children = $elem.children();
for ( var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    var id = children[ i ].id;

    //was this id previously seen?
    if ( ids.hasOwnProperty(id) ) {
        $( children[i] ).remove();
    }
    //a brand new id was discovered!
    else {
        ids[ id ] = true;
    }
}
//done!
```

This is the very simple, plain logic version. You can make much fancier ways with some weird sizzle selectors, but this should get you started.

Demo (without jquery): http://tinkerbin.com/qGJpPsAQ

Comment: better than regexp, but I'd personally rather see the said unique element never be appended.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work but it only removes the second element that has the same ID, try this:

```
$('[id]').each(function() {
    var $ids = $('[id=' + this.id + ']');
    if ($ids.length > 1) {
        $ids.not(':first').remove();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3WUwZ/